# Precompilation of ASP.NET Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to precompile (for deployment) an ASP.NET Web Application with Visual Studio 2008. I want to do this as it is described at http://dotnetperls.com/precompiled-aspnet, but my Publish dialog is different.

My publish dialog has the following appearance:

- Target Location

  - Replace matching files with local copies
  - Delete all existing files prior to publish
- Copy

  - Only files needed to run this application
  - All project files
  - All files in the source project folder
  - Include files from the App_Data folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're trying to publish a Web Application-Project, not a Website. In Visual Studio, there is a difference between these two. If possible, you can convert the project to a website. That way you get the dialog you want.

More on the differences between these two can be found at: http://damieng.com/blog/2008/02/07/web-site-vs-web-application